# Conditional statements PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am looking for a simple example to create a conditional statement in the pyQGIS console.

Today I wrote a simple script to add a field [CAT] to a vector layer. This script can be found below. I want to add a conditional statement to this script based on the field [SURFACE] to make the following statement:

- If [Surface] > 10000: return "big city" to field [CAT]
- Elif [Surface] > 10000: return "metropolis" to field [CAT]
- Else: return "small city" to field [CAT]

SCRIPT:

```
fn = path to the file

layer=iface.addVectorLayer(fn, '', 'ogr')
features=layer.getFeatures()
caps=layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps&QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    res=layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("CAT", QVariant.String)])
    layer.updateFields()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way will be:

```
with edit(layer):
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        if feature['surface']>10000:
             feature['CAT']='big city'
        elif...
        else...
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a full example using `changeAttributeValues()`:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # the layer to work with
surfacefield = 'surface' # fieldname of your lookup field
catfield = 'CAT' # fieldname of your new field

with edit(layer): # start edit mode of the layer
    layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(catfield , QVariant.String)]) # add the new field to the layer
    layer.updateFields() # update the fields, so we can find it
    fieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName(catfield) # get the index of this new field

    for feature in layer.getFeatures(): # iterate over layer
        category = '' # reset category (actually not really needed)
        if feature[surfacefield] > 10000: # if the surface field is bigger 10000 set the category to big city
            category = 'big city'
        elif feature[surfacefield] < 10000 and feature[surfacefield] > 100:
            category = 'metropolis'
        else:
            category = 'small city'
        attrs =  { fieldindex : category } # defining the new attribute (category) to the new field (CAT)
        layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({ feature.id() : attrs }) # add this definition to the current feature
```